# Throw an Exception When a JFrame is Closed

Tags: java, swing, exception, jframe

I would like to throw an exception whenever the user closes a window, but I'm not sure if this is possible. Here is some code of what I would like to do:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ExceptionTest extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new ExceptionTest();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ExceptionTest() throws Exception{
        super("Exception Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                super.windowClosed(e);
                //Throw Exception
            }
        });

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why? Did you try to throw an exception?

Comment: Just throw your exception normally after the `super.windowClosed(e)` call.

Comment: You can sure throw the Exception. The real question is who do you want to catch that Exception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RunTimeException` instead as follows:

```
public ExceptionTest()  {
    super("Exception Test");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e)throws RuntimeException {
            throw new RuntimeException("WindowClosedException");
        }
    });
```

Comment: How would I catch this now? It is just printing the stack trace even if I remove e.printStackTrace() from my catch block.

Comment: After your window is closed..your JVm is exited..What will you do by catching that exception?

Comment: In my actual program that I will implement this in, I will have a few windows open so I want to be able to catch it so I know the window was closed.

Comment: So you want to keep track of how many window is closed..right?

Comment: Not quite. I created a menu to connect to a server. The menu has connect and disconnect as options. I don't want connect enabled if you are already connected, and disconnect should not be enabled if you are connected. When I open a "connection window," then close it, I want to have that throw an exception so I can catch it and set my JMenuItems to be correctly enabled. Should I be looking into a different way to do this?

Comment: Take a flag `f` in the class containing your main Frame.And instead of `JFrame` use `JDialog` as `connection Window`. While your connection Window is opened .. and you make connection successfully then put `f` as `true` and make your `disconnect` menuitem `enabled` and `connect` menuitem `disabled` else do just opposite

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can throw any kind of RuntimeExceptions there.
You can find the list of RuntimeExceptions here: [RuntimeException (Java Platform SE 6)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ExceptionTest extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new ExceptionTest();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ExceptionTest() throws Exception{
    super("Exception Test");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
            super.windowClosed(e);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("User closed this window!");
        }
    });

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can throw a RuntimeException

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                super.windowClosed(e);
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
         });
```